# 2D Grid Exploration/Traversal

Tags: algorithm, grid, traversal

I am currently working on a school project for multiagent systems and I'm looking for recommendations for pathfinding and exploration algorithms. The relevant problem description is as follows:

a) The agent is in a 2D rectangular grid of known, fixed but arbitrary dimensions.

b) The agent can only move in one of four directions, one square per simulation time step.

c) The agent has a fixed sensor range. It is able to see, for example, a 2-square radius around itself - a 5x5 grid centred on the agent.

d) Cells may contain obstacles which block the agent's movement but not vision.
Obstacles are created at initialisation, are non-perishable, and no new obstacle will spawn mid-simulation.

e) All cells can be accessed from any adjacent cell.

f) Other in-world objects relevant to the agent's goals exist. They do not block the agent, but they spawn and despawn with a lifetime determined by a Normal/Gaussian distribution (parameters unknown to agent but it is allowed to guess on observations).

g) For a sense of the project's scale, the agent will be assessed in three scenarios: 50x50, 100x100, and the last with undisclosed dimensions (to the developer)

There are three different types of scenarios for which I need to generate a path for, and I've identified a possible algorithm:

1) Shortest path to a known refuelling point. The map may not be fully explored yet. I'm considering to use A*.

2) Map exploration. The agent may, at any arbitrary position, choose to initiate exploration mode. I need to get the shortest path to SENSE all cells in one pass. Known obstacle cells can be ignored. Revisiting cells is allowed but should be minimised, as implied by shortest path. I'm considering BFS for this but I honestly have no idea. I tried Googling but the results are all about real robots with hardware sensors. I'm not dealing with hardware here.

3) A variation of traveller's salesman. The agent maintains two sets of waypoints, let's say A and B. When it chooses to do so, it will alternate between waypoints from each set. The agent needs to visit every complete pair of AB-waypoints in the shortest path or, if not possible due to situational limits on path length, the shortest path to earn the highest score possible in that particular pass. The scoring function is the percentage of all pairs spawned that are visited.

Time does not pass and the world does not change while the agent is thinking and planning. Also, no penalty or constraint is imposed on the agent's execution time, so I can afford to look for optimal algorithms as opposed to greedy ones, and pruning of the plan's length is not necessary.

I am capable of tweaking general algorithms to fit my specific contexts and internal logic, but I need help to set me in the correct direction, especially for the latter two scenarios which seem to be common problems in my encounters but aren't mentioned in textbook scenarios. Thanks!